# Need some data after by grouping on key in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by

I have a problem in spark(v2.2.2)/scala(v2.11.8). Mostly into scala/spark functional language.

I have a list of person with rented_date like below.
These are csv file which I will convert into parquet and read as a dataframe.

Table: Person

```
+-------------------+-----------+
|         ID        |report_date|
+-------------------+-----------+
|                123| 2011-09-25|
|                111| 2017-08-23|
|                222| 2018-09-30|
|                333| 2020-09-30|
|                444| 2019-09-30|
+-------------------+-----------+
```

I want to find out the start_date of the address for the period person's rented it out by grouping on ID

Table: Address

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|       ID          |start_date|close_date|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|                123|2008-09-23|2009-09-23|
|                123|2009-09-24|2010-09-23|
|                123|2010-09-24|2011-09-23|
|                123|2011-09-30|2012-09-23|
|                123|2012-09-24|      null|
|                111|2013-09-23|2014-09-23|
|                111|2014-09-24|2015-09-23|
|                111|2015-09-24|2016-09-23|
|                111|2016-09-24|2017-09-23|
|                111|2017-09-24|      null|
|                222|2018-09-24|      null|
+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

ex: For 123 rented_date is 2011-09-20, which in address table falls in the period (start_date, close_date) 2010-09-24,2011-09-23 (row 3 in address). Form here I have to fetch start_date 2010-09-24.

I have to do this on entire dataset by joining the tables. Or need to fetch start_date from address table into the Person table.
Also need to handle where closed date is null.

Sometime scenario may also include where rented date will not fall in any of the period in that case we need to take it where rented_date < closed_date.

Apologies, proper format of tables are not populating.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Good idea to provide expected output and what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all

> I have a list of person with rented_date like below. These are csv file which I will convert into parquet and read as a dataframe.

No need to convert it you can just read it directly with spark

```
spark.read.csv("path")
spark.read.format("csv").load("path")
```

I am not sure what your expectation in null fields are so I would filter them out for now:

```
dfAdressNotNull.filter($"close_date".isNotNull)
```

Of course now you need to join them together and since the data in Address is the relevant one I would do a left join.

```
val joinedDf = dfAddressNotNull.join(dfPerson, Seq("ID"), "left")
```

No you have Addresses and Persons combined

If you filter now like that

```
joinedDf.filter($"report_date" >= $"start_date" && $"report_date" < $"closed_date")
```

You should have something like that what you want to achieve.